# Using tortoisesvn and visualsvn remotely

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have installed TortoiseSVN on a server on which i am connected remotely. Now i installed VisualSVN on my machine and i want to access from Visual Studio the repository which was made on the server where TortoiseSVN is installed. How to do this?

Comment: TortoiseSVN is not a server, it is a client. If you want to access the repos remotely -- install SVN server such as VisualSVN Server and use HTTP(S).

Comment: @bahrep i installed svn server on the hosted server, bot nou when i try to import my project from computer to server, i received error such as "cant connect to url repository"

Answer (score 1):

1) Install **VisualSVNServer**, on your Server.

link: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/

2) Create your Repositories on server with **VisualSVNServer**.

3) Install **Tortoise + VisualSVN**, on your local machine.

link: https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/

4) in VisualStudio add your Solution to Repositories on Server.

5) Done!